# Прекращена работа программы VS 2013

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Проблема появляется при работе с WinForms (c#), при добавлении любого элемента имеющего область (panel, pictureBox и др.)

> Полный текст ошибки:
>  
>     Сигнатура проблемы:
>     Имя события проблемы: APPCRASH
>     Имя приложения:   devenv.exe
>     Версия приложения:    12.0.31101.0
>     Отметка времени приложения:   54548724
>     Имя модуля с ошибкой: msvcrt.dll
>     Версия модуля с ошибкой:  7.0.7601.17744
>     Отметка времени модуля с ошибкой: 4eeaf722
>     Код исключения:   c0000005
>     Смещение исключения:  00009b60
>     Версия ОС:    6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
>     Код языка:    1049
>     Дополнительные сведения 1:    0a9e
>     Дополнительные сведения 2:    0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
>     Дополнительные сведения 3:    0a9e
>     Дополнительные сведения 4:    0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

Пробовал переустанавливать среду, запускать в безопасном режиме без расширений, обновился до последней версии - не помогает.

Comment: Запустите под дебаггером (можете запустить два экземпляра VS и прицепить один к другому).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте воспроизвести проблему под другим пользователем на той же машине. Если под други пользователем работает без ошибки - удалите из реестра ключ `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio`
 - это сбросит настройки.

Comment: Увы, ошибка появляется и там. Попробовал отдебажить VS - результат: http://i.imgur.com/9U9Zaeu.png

Comment: отключите "только мой код" и покажите stack trace. пока видно только что это AccessViolation в System.Drawing. Это может быть вызвано битой памятью или драйвером видеокарты.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/12g8GjI.png - стэк вызовов. http://i.imgur.com/SlY1JJD.png - вывод. Заметил, что при выводе у некоторых .dll файлов написано, что "Невозможно найти или открыть PDB-файл". Например, у "VS 2013\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.Designers.BusinessDataConnectivity.Dsl.dl". Надеюсь, это не критично. P.S драйвера видеокарты актуальны. Интересно то, что эта проблема возникла сразу на двух устройствах: Настольном ПК и ноутбуке. На последнем, переустановив ОС, проблема решилась сама собой.

Answer (score 0):

> Имя модуля с ошибкой: msvcrt.dll

Ну думаю понятно что сбой выдает установленная библиотека MS Visual C++. Переустановите ее(удалить, потом установить), скачав с официального сайта, до нужной версии для вашего Visual Studio.

Comment: PS: скорее всего у вас эта библиотека была установлена или испорчена после установки какой-либо игры.. с играми часто прилетает что попало или неполноценное.

Comment: c0000005 - это null reference. в какую-то стандартную функцию C++ передали null, там где ожидался не null. проблема скорее всего в вызывающем коде, а не в самой библиотеке.

Comment: Он  же не запускает приложение свое, а пытается в режиме разработки добавить компонент на форму, что является проблемой среды разработки, а не его собственного кода.

Comment: да. какой-то код внутри devenv,exe делает кривой вызов какой-то стандартной функции C++. проблема в devenv.exe, а не в библиотеке.